# Is there a difference between these two ways of using foreach?

Tags: c#, optimization, foreach, properties

Is there a difference between the two code snippets shown below?

1. Property loaded into variable before the `foreach` clause.

   ```
   var someCollection = someClass.Collection;
   foreach (var elem in someCollection)
   {
       // Do something
   }
   ```
2. Property accessed inline within the `foreach` clause.

   ```
   foreach (var elem in someClass.Collection)
   {
       // Do something
   }
   ```

Is second variant less optimized and if so, why?

Comment: Do you have some reason to think there is a difference in the optimized CLR code for these two examples?

Comment: It was second situation about perfomance differences. I think it is related to previous one and there is no need to open another question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is **no difference** between the two approaches, optimization- or performance-wise. To prove this, I have created a brief example similar to yours:

```
public class C {
    public void A() {
        foreach (var item in SomeClass.Collection) {}
    }

    public void B() {
        var someCollection = SomeClass.Collection;
        foreach (var item in someCollection) {}
    }   
}

public static class SomeClass {
    public static List<string> Collection { get; set; }
}
```

When compiled using the [Roslyn .NET compiler](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn) version 2.9.0, both methods `A` and `B` result in the very same intermediate code as shown below (**[reference](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQDABCCMAsDcBYAUCkBmKAmCBhCA3ihCVJiLBAIIAUAlIcacwGYD2ATgKYCGAxgAsINAG48OEAJYAXLgFspAOwgBlNnK64ANjwDOugHS42WrVz7TJbRQwIBfJiQfJmjiG4xRKAIXqMXzKRiErrqmiZmFlbKALyqYdp6hsam5pbWSAGBEOzc/AKi4lKyCpLKoRopkek2hM7MdqQo9U2oyJ4wAGzY8ZU6+v7MHdDdADKSutIAPDBgAHx4EWnRhBAA5lzS8BC6m9vOdkA)**).

***Method Body of `A` and `B`***

```
List<string>.Enumerator enumerator = SomeClass.Collection.GetEnumerator();
try
{
    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        string current = enumerator.Current;
    }
}
finally
{
    ((IDisposable)enumerator).Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference in performance or optimization. The only difference is that you have one more variable in your code, which holds a reference (an address, a "pointer") to your collection.